# Eclipse c++ MakeFile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I am new to Eclipse and I am am trying to include a make command within Eclipse. Currently I run make from the command line.

I have tried various things to have it within the Eclipse framework - but I need help. Where do I put my make command which is just:

```
make headers; make lib
```

- and how do I "call" it

Answer (score 0):

to set the build command for your project : 
project-properties->c/c++ build->Build command x

now just hit ctrl+b. is this what you need?

Comment: Hi,I get error in Console Tab:

make headers;make lib all
make: *** No rule to make target 'headers;make'. Stop.

Comment: maybe you need to call it from your /debug directory? make sure in the same window that the build directory is right.

Answer (score 0):

or you can press `ctrl+f9` and add your build target like **headers** or **lib** and then build last target using just `f9` or chose target with `ctrl+f9`